# How to find the text ween two specified characters using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having the following text

```
var str = "/*Is this all there is?*/ Stack over flow"
```

In this text I need to replace the text between `"/* ....*/"` with empty string ''.

So the result has to be `str = "Stack over flow".`

How can I achieve this using regex?

How to make the regex for the text starting with `"/*"` and ending with `"*/"` and text in between this?

Comment: what you tried, try something at online regex tools

Answer (score 4):

you can use `/\/(.)*\//g` using backslashes you can escape '/'. you need to start and end with '/' but you will need to use escape character '\' to use '/' in regular expression, so it becomes `\/\/` then you also need to match any character between these, for that use (.)* as . matches any character and * for any number of times. so regex becomes `/\/(.)*\//`

```js
var str = "/*Is this all there is?*/ Stack over flow";

console.log(str.replace(/\/(.)*\//g,""));
```

Comment: Hi Diji,
Thanks for your answer, Can you please explain your expression. I am new to regexp

Comment: Nitpicking, but you could drop the parenthesis. `.*` works just as well.

Comment: If the string is like str = "@charcter  /*Is this all there is?*/ Stack over flow".

How to remove others except stack over slow in this text

Comment: @NimrodArgov used parantheses to make it more clear.

Comment: @Joy in that case you can check for string ending with `*/`.